# MacVim/YADR Autocomplete Issue

Tags: vim, autocomplete, zsh, macvim

I have installed MacVim, and https://github.com/skwp/dotfiles (including all the dependencies such as zsh, etc). and I am having trouble getting auto complete to work.

When I'm typing

`<tit` a pink box shows up with `<title>Index</title>` and according to the https://github.com/skwp/dotfiles documentation pressing <kbd>tab</kbd> will make it autocomplete. Which sometimes works, sometimes it just adds two spaces, however that's not really my question.

When it does auto complete it turns it into

`<<title>Index</title>>` notice the two `<` and `>`

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wow… 79 plugins? Really?

At a low level, your problem is that you give someone else too much power over *your* configuration, *your* toolset and *your* workflow.

At a higher level, you are probably misusing your config's auto-completion feature. I *think* that you have a conflict between the `neocomplcache`, `delimitmate` and `snipmate` plugins: the 1st deals with auto-completion, the 2nd automatically closes pairs of characters (`<>`,`""`,`()`…) while the 3rd does "tab-expansion" on the `tit` keyword.

Basically, I believe that you are supposed to type `tit<Tab>` instead of `<tit<Tab>` to avoid triggering `delimitmate`.